# Angular cli not working in Git Bash terminal on Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I've been trying to install the Angular CLI via npm. My current node version is `v11.2.0` and my npm  version is `6.4.1`.

After running the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` I get this output:

```
C:\Users\Mark O'Hare\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Mark O'Hare\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

and when I try `ng -v` I get this error message:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Users\Mark O'Hare\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:826:3)
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Uninstalling angular via npm and reinstalling
- Uninstalling node.js and deleting npm folders, restarting machine and reinstalling
- Creating alias's for 'ng' with the path to the ng file in the npm node_modules folder

So far none of these have worked. Can anyone help or suggest a workaround?

Comment: Try downgrading to Node 10.13.0, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem lies within the user folder Mark O'Hare:

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\c\Users\Mark O'Hare\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng' --> it reads the string until the second apostrophe, which is inside O'Hare, ultimately reading the folder as

C:\c\Users\Mark O

Comment: I suspected that might be an issue. Is it safe to just rename that folder or is that configured somewhere in windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use linux subsystem.
I would recommend it as it's easier to make JS env working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 0):

i think folder name  **Mark O'Hare** is the issue. 
Instead of global installation try to install it in local and try to run the cli